# React native FlatList render/display text on the same line

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, styles, react-native-flatlist

I am rendering a list of text in react native using FlatList and I am facing a problem, I can't render/display text on the same line, I want to display text in the form of a paragraph. By default, FlatList renders every item on a new line.

**Code**

```js
<FlatList
   data={list}
   renderItem={({ item }) => (
       <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{item.text}</Text>
    )}
/>
```

**Output:**

This is Text 1
This is Text 2
This is Text 3
This is Text 4

**Expected Output**

This is Text 1
This is Text 2
This is Text 3
This is Text 4

**Solutions I have tried**

I have tried using flex-wrap with FlastList but it's not supported yet.

This problem can be solved by using ScrollView, but my list is really big and it has a lot of performance issues, the text automatically resizes randomly. My original list has text in Arabic.

I have also tried `horizontal={true}` and `numColumns={2}` but it adds white space between the paragraphs.

***Example***

This is Text 1 * *white-space*  * This is
Text 2 This  is * *white-space* * Text 3

Please let me know if it is possible to render text in this way using FlatList.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you please add the code of your styles.textStyle?

Comment: @wassimAJ styles.textStyle only includes fontSize and fontFamily.

Answer (score 2):

That is what you want:

```
 <FlatList
   data={list}
   renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{item.text}</Text>}
   horizontal={true}
   ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <Text> </Text>}
  />
```

When you add the numColumns={2}, it means that you want it to be separated into two columns, so instead I added ItemSeparatorComponent. How does it work?

It renders a component **between** each item from the data you're using.
In this case, I added a component that contains a single space in order to separate them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this solution puts everything on the same line and this is what my question asked for, but what I am looking for is when content can't fit on the screen it should move to the next line. Sorry, I didn't clarify the question.

Comment: @AnasIkhlas Then simply do the following:


<View>
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{list.map(item => ` ${item}`)}</Text>
    </View>